# Which is faster: 4 lines or a rectangle SWT Java

Tags: java, swt

Is there any performance differences between 4 lines or a rectangle when it comes to drawing in SWT. Even if its a small difference I am interested. The system I am creating can makes a ton of these calls per frame.

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking it?

Answer (score 3):

On a system I work on, after profiling it, we switched from drawing one rectangle + two lines for a polyline and we got a great boost on drawing. (to draw candles like those:

[image]

)

It was, at least, twice as fast.

Comment: Very interesting did you still use to a rectangle to fill the poly then? Made my laugh a little that the response that I received happened to be a chart related solution as well. :) So when you started drawing a fair amount of candlesticks on a chart, you saw a mark improvement?

Comment: We don't use rectangles anymore.  We use `gc.fillPolygon( polyLine )` and `gc.drawPolygon( polyLine )`.  It's way faster than the previous approach.

Comment: I see you have written a comment about this post http://richclientplatform.blogspot.com/2007/08/high-performance-graphics-with-swt.html  -- Did you not end up going the route of image data manipulation?

Comment: No, I didn't.  For vertical and horizontal lines that would be great, but when it comes to diagonals and circles, it would require too much math.  The polygon approach was a far better and easier solution.

Comment: Ok, Thank you again for the information. This stuff seems largely undocumented anywhere.